# regex Pattern Matcher, how to store the rest of the string

Tags: java, regex

String : USA (45)

using pattern matching getting only numeric value 45

Java code

```
ArrayList<String> portfolioCount = new ArrayList<String>();
String mainText = USA (45)
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(mainText);
m.find();           
portfolioCount.add(m.group(1));
```

store the numeric value into an arrayList,
my question is how to store the rest of the String (i.e USA) into another array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookahead and lookbehind in order not to include the parenthesis in the matched group:

```
ArrayList<String> countryCount = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> portfolioCount = new ArrayList<String>();
String mainText = "USA (45)";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?>\\()(\\d+)(?=\\)).*");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(mainText);
m.find();
countryCount.add(m.group(1)); //USA
portfolioCount.add(m.group(2)); //45
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(.*?)\\s*\\((.*?)\\)
```

Try this.Grab the match1 and match2.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/7

Answer (score 1):

Just capture the part before the number within () to another group,

```
ArrayList<String> portfolioCount = new ArrayList<String>();
String mainText = "USA (45)";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s+\\((.*?)\\)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(mainText);
while(m.find()){           
portfolioCount.add(m.group(1));
portfolioCount.add(m.group(2));
System.out.println(portfolioCount);
}
```

**Output**

```
[USA, 45]
```

To store the country name and count into two separate lists,

```
ArrayList<String> portfolioCount = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<String>();
String mainText = "USA (45)";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s+\\((.*?)\\)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(mainText);
while(m.find()){           
portfolioCount.add(m.group(1));
country.add(m.group(2));
System.out.println(portfolioCount);
System.out.println(country);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[USA]
[45]
```